# Reading complex binary file in python

Tags: python

I am rather new to python programming so please be a big simple with your answer.

I have a .raw file which is 2b/2b complex short int format. Its actually a 2-D raster file. I want to read and seperate both real and complex parts. Lets say the raster is [MxN] size.

Please let me know if question is not clear.

Cheers
N

Comment: The `struct` module is the usual way this is handled...if the file format itself isn't _too_ complex. ;-)

Comment: no its not... but i am a bit confused about data types. In matlab I use float32 but in other software I used int16 and it worked.

Comment: I don't know about `matlab`, but a 2 byte integer can be read by `struct` using the `'h'` format. So for example, to read a single complex number in the format you describe could be done with something like `struct.unpack('>hh', '\x00\x01\x00\x02')` which would return the tuple `(1, 2)` -- and could easily be turned into a Python complex numeric type using the `complex()` function. If you describe the file format in more detail a better answer might be possible.

Comment: yes. It is a 2byte/2byte int. So for [M,N] image, an array of [M*N,1] is created where first N number are real part of complex number of first row and next N are imaginary. repeat the same M times. I hope you understand file format now. Its raw generic binary without any header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it with the `struct` module. Here's a simple example based on the file formatting information you mentioned in a comment:

```
import struct

def read_complex_array(filename, M, N):
    row_fmt = '={}h'.format(N)  # "=" prefix means integers in native byte-order
    row_len = struct.calcsize(row_fmt)
    result = []
    with open(filename, "rb" ) as input:
        for col in xrange(M):
            reals = struct.unpack(row_fmt, input.read(row_len))
            imags = struct.unpack(row_fmt, input.read(row_len))
            cmplx = [complex(r,i) for r,i in zip(reals, imags)]
            result.append(cmplx)
    return result
```

This will return a list of complex-number lists, as can be seen in this output from a trivial test I ran:

```
[
  [  0.0+  1.0j    1.0+  2.0j    2.0+  3.0j    3.0+  4.0j],
  [256.0+257.0j  257.0+258.0j  258.0+259.0j  259.0+260.0j],
  [512.0+513.0j  513.0+514.0j  514.0+515.0j  515.0+516.0j]
]
```

Both the real and imaginary parts of complex numbers in Python are usually represented as a pair of machine-level double precision floating point numbers.

You could also use the `array` module. Here's the same thing using it:

```
import array

def read_complex_array2(filename, M, N):
    result = []
    with open(filename, "rb" ) as input:
        for col in xrange(M):
            reals = array.array('h')
            reals.fromfile(input, N)
            # reals.byteswap()  # if necessary
            imags = array.array('h')
            imags.fromfile(input, N)
            # imags.byteswap()  # if necessary
            cmplx = [complex(r,i) for r,i in zip(reals, imags)]
            result.append(cmplx)
    return result
```

As you can see, they're very similar, so it's not clear there's a big advantage to using one over the other. I suspect the `array` based version might be faster, but that would have to be determined by actually timing it with some real data to be able to say with any certainty.

Comment: thank you. It worked. I didn't check speed. I will test later again and post which one is faster.

Comment: You're welcome -- and thanks for accepting my answer. There are other, trickier and likely faster ways of doing it than what I wrote, but I tried to keep things simple and understandable. Please let us know what you're timing measurements are after you've made them.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Hachoir](https://bitbucket.org/haypo/hachoir/wiki/Home) library. It's designed for this purposes, and does it's work really good.